# How to automatic backup SQL server registered servers?

Tags: backup, sql-server

I have many servers registered. I don't know where this information is saved. After PC rebuild, they are gone. Is there way to schedule task to backup this information?

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS, you have an option to export/import registered server information, see these BOL links: [Export](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190246.aspx), [Import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190711.aspx).

Another option is that you designate an instance of SQL Server as a [Central Management Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934126.aspx) (CMS). No need to export/import registered servers for a PC rebuild in that case, since registered servers' info is saved on the CMS.